# how to color scale a continuous variable using cscale and viridis palette for igraph plot?

Tags: r, igraph

I am plotting a biological trasnport network in igraph (in R) where I want to show edges in a color gradient based on an edge attribute (which is a continuous variable called "width" in my case). I do not like the default color palette obtained in:

```
plot(graph, edge.color=E(graph)$width)
```

Looking at the igraph plot help I found a way to change this palette using cscale from the scales package:

```
plot(graph,
edge.color=cscale(E(graph)$width,palette = seq_gradient_pal(low = "yellow",high = "red")))
```

That works fine and may stick to it. However I was wondering whether I could use either viridis or colorbrewer palettes. I have not figured out how to do it. The main issue is that I cannot manage to assign color coding to all edges. For example if I just do this:

```
plot(graph,
 edge.color=cscale(E(graph)$width,palette = viridis_pal())
```

I get this warning:

```
In seq.default(begin, end, length.out = n) :
  first element used of 'length.out' argument
```

And indeed the first color is applied to all edges

If I try to specify the length of all edges:

```
plot(graph,
 edge.color=cscale(E(graph)$width,palette = viridis_pal()(ecount(graph))
```

I get this error message:

```
Error in palette(x) : invalid argument type)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: please provide a reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem --- I wanted to color edges using the viridis palette --- that I solved with [SymbolixAU's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5977215/symbolixau) [colourvalues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55111088/viridis-with-colorramppalette-output-different-vector-lengths-in-r).

```
library(igraph)
library(viridis)
library(colourvalues)


# read in data frame with pairwise distances, 
# convert to lower triangular matrix, and 
# stash the column names for later use.  Then,

g <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(m,mode="lower",weighted=TRUE,add.colnames=TRUE)
V(g)$name <- colnames(m)
E(g)$color <- colour_values(E(g)$weight,palette = "viridis")
plot(g, vertex.label=V(g)$name,edge.width = E(g)$weight/10, edge.label=E(g)$weight,edge.color=E(g)$color)
```

Warmest thanks, SymbolixAU!

Comment: Great!! Thanks for posting!